# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make a timer app. The user will input seconds and the seek bar moves in a decreasing manner. But as soon as I click on the button, the progress bar moves to the value, but the app crashes. I think the code is working fine till the progress bar update, but after that, it crashes. I have been struggling with this code for hours. Please help, I am a newbie in android app development.

Here is the log:-

```
2020-02-11 13:17:21.081 4121-4121/com.example.timer E/m.example.time: Invalid ID 0x00000004.
2020-02-11 13:17:21.081 4121-4121/com.example.timer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-02-11 13:17:21.083 4121-4121/com.example.timer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.timer, PID: 4121
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5846)
    at com.example.timer.MainActivity$1.onTick(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:130)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6715)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Enter Time In Seconds"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="99dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="248dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="163dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
package com.example.timer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void start(View view){
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        int timeGiven = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        seekBar.setMax(timeGiven);
        seekBar.setProgress(timeGiven);

        new CountDownTimer(timeGiven*1000, 1000){
            public void onTick(long millisecondsLeft){

                int secondsLeft = (int) millisecondsLeft/1000;
                seekBar.setProgress(secondsLeft);
                textView.setText(secondsLeft);
            }
            public void onFinish(){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BOOM",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: onTick run on background thread , so run by runOnUIThread or using view handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is here:

```
textView.setText(secondsLeft);
```

try:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
```

It's not possible to place integer values into TextView.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, thanks @ivan-ardelian